# Can latexmk be told to ignore specific intermediate files completely?

Tags: latexmk, comments

One `latex` run suffices to generate the DVI/PDF version of the LaTeX document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\includecomment{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{comment}
  \noindent
  Test
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

By contrast, `latexmk` thinks that two `latex` runs are necessary. The reason for this is the following: Since comments are to be included the `comment` environment writes its content to an intermediate file (by default `comment.cut`). `Latexmk` treats `comment.cut` similar to other intermediate files (such as the `toc` and `lof` files) and thus provides for another `latex` run. What `latexmk` misses is that `comment.cut` is input right at the end of the `comment` environment and that it’s useless afterwards. Hence, the second `latex` run is superfluous.

Does anybody know whether it’s possible to configure `latexmk` such that it completely ignores specific intermediate files?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to submit this is as a bug report to the latexmk developers?

Comment: @N.N.: If nobody suggests a reasonable workaround by means of customization I’ll do so. Possibly, similar issues arise with packages other than the `comment` package.

Comment: I just meant that if this is non-intended or problematic behavior of latexmk it would make sense to let the developers know.

Comment: Have you tried to run latexmk with the `-diagnostics` option to better understand its behavior? It is described as follows in the manual: "Print detailed diagnostics during a run. This may help for debugging problems or to understand latexmk's behavior in difficult situations."

Comment: @N.N.: `comment.cut` is correctly detected as dependent file since it’s written by `(pdf)latex`. But, probably, it should not be treated as a source file. Then, the `(pdf)latex` rule might not consider it a prerequisite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mhp: Your diagnosis is correct.  `comment.cut` is detected as a dependent file, and `latexmk` does a rerun of the `(pdf)latex` rule when it sees that a dependent file has changed.  It makes no attempt to determine whether the change has an actual effect on the output.

With current implementations of `tex`, the recorder option is available, and can be used by `latexmk`.  There is then sufficient information to determine whether a file is read only after it has been written in the same run.  It would be a useful optimization for `latexmk` to detect this situation, and deal with it.  I'll add it to the list of improvements.

Note that the excess rerun is normally rare: it only happens if the contents of the comment environment have changed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Actually, I only noticed the excess reruns since, in my specific case, they happen every time: I use two differently named comment environments to typeset two versions of a document simultaneously.